# Reset perspective to default

Tags: eclipse-rcp, talend

I'm using `Talend Data Integration` v.5.2.1r95165 (which is the latest release) and I can't find a way to reset the `Integration` (or any other) perspective to its defaults.

There isn't anything under the Window menu, and the reset button under the Preferences menu is disabled.

Any clues ? Maybe there is a way to manually delete or update some `.properties` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the perspective from the perspective toolbar. Right click on the selected perspective and then reset.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's so simple, can't imagine I didn't try that before ! I'm used to find something under Window -> Reset perspective